# Dimmensionality reduction for highly dimensional multivariate time series with few time steps

Tags: time-series, dimensionality-reduction, lstm, high-dimensional

I am looking for a dimmensionality reduction technique that is ideally compatible with LSTM. The dataset I am working with is a multivariate time series with 10 time points and ~13000 features. The goal is build a binary classification model for the dataset. There are only 50 samples.

Using data from just a single time point, I can train an MLP classifier to achieve 73% accuracy (LOOCV) and an F1 score of 0.71 after PCA prepossessing. 
This leads me to believe that there is a signal in the spatial structure of the data, and using a classifier like an LSTM network might be able to improve upon this by capturing a temporal signal.

Unfortunately, preliminary results with single layer LSTM (10,000 neurons) only produces around 60% cross validation accuracy on a 70/30 test train split. It is obvious that I need to employ a dimmensionality reduction technique, but I am unsure of one that is suited for so few time steps. Most techniques I have come across utilize Fourier transformations, however I have a hard time believing that there is much information in the frequency spectrum of such a short sequence.

Any ideas on techniques to try would be much appreciated. I am also unsure if LSTM is even suitable for such a short sequence, but I have had poor results with alternative methods (DTW with K-NN, SVM with time-series kernel).